# Tag resources when registering to the environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a pipeline with multiple stages that deploys groups of virtual machines.
And registers one to and azure pipelines environment.

Then I want to target that registered VM in a deployment job.

I have a problem to target that resource by name as the resource does not exists in the environment at queue time so I cannot even disable the stage before running.

So my next option is targeting by tags.
But I saw no option in the registration script to define tags at registering time.

So my pipeline flow has a manual step between stages to go to the environment and tag the resource.
Then I can trigger the deployments stage of the pipeline and it continues ok.

So my question is:

There is any way of disabling the resource evaluation at queuetime or anyway to tag resoureces in the environment programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Adding my registration script:
From the azagent directory.
./config.sh --unattended --environment --environmentname "myenv" --acceptteeeula --agent $HOSTNAME --url https://dev.azure.com/company/ --work _work --projectname 'MIPROJECT' --auth PAT --token $AGENT_REGISTRATION_PAT --runasservice; sudo ./svc.sh install; sudo ./svc.sh start";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I saw no option in the registration script to define tags at
> registering time.

When running the Registration script, there will be a step: `Enter Environment Virtual Machine resource tags? (Y/N) (press enter for N)`, at this time you need to enter **Y**, and then in the next step: `Enter Comma separated list of tags (e.g web, db)` define the tag for the resource.

[image]

**Update**:

You can add `--addvirtualmachineresourcetags --virtualmachineresourcetags "<tag>"` to the registration script.

You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837145/11508192) for details.

Comment: Yes when you register interactively the option is there but I didn't found a command line option for the unattended case.

Comment: You can add this:`--addvirtualmachineresourcetags --virtualmachineresourcetags "<tag>"` to the registration script.

Comment: @Alfonso Graña Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.